# Kmail cannot send to smtp.office365.com

Tags: networking, email, kmail

My corporate email is hosted by Office365. I think KMail is far more productive an email client than the Outlook Web Application (OWA), so I use IMAP to receive email and SMTP to send email.

I can receive email fine, but on certain networks I cannot send mail. For example, GoGo Inflight Internet (gogoair) or some of the corporate networks of my clients. On these networks, I get the following error from KMail:

> Failed to transport message. smtp.office365.com: Socket operation timed out

Sending email to Gmail via SMTP through the same port (587) works fine.

I have configured KMail to send email as follows:
Outgoing mail server: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption: TLS

I have tried:

- Lengthening the socket timeout
- Disabling IPV6
- Disabling TCP Timestamps

but I see no change in behavior.

I don't see anything relevant in the journal, akonadi logs, or .xsession-errors

Anyone have a suggestion on what else I can try?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because having a port blocked in some networks is not a Unix problem.

Comment: As I noted in the question, it is not a blocked port. I can send to the same port through Gmail.

Comment: Can you connect at all? ``openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.office365.com:587``

Comment: I would recommend asking Microsoft then.

Comment: Microsoft says that KMail is not a supported SMTP client. <grumble>

Comment: @phg: you provided me a way to prove that it is a network issue and not a KMail issue. If you post it as a response, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify connectivity to STARTTLS enabled services using
the apps that ship with OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.office365.com:587
```

If this succeeds, it will dump extensive information about the
servers’s SSL configuration and the handshake to the terminal.
You should then be able to talk to the server using ordinary SMTP
(send it an `EHLO` for example).

Otherwise you get either a connection error or a timeout.

In case of `smtp.office365.com` the handshake is successful
from here.

For more protocols supported with the `-starttls` parameter see
the OpenSSL documentation:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/s_client.html

Comment: Thanks for the help phg! I should have thought to test the connectivity with OpenSSL before blaming KMail.